# How to get value of data attribute from button to controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

How can we get the data attribute value from button to controller in laravel
My button

```
<input type="submit" value="Add click" name="submit" id="submit" data-name="{{$value->name}}" data-click="{{$value->click}}">
```

i want to get `data-click` and `data-name` pass it to controller

```
$click=data-click;
$name=data-name;
```

from button attribute after submit form to controller

But the result not get the data-name and data-click value. How can we try this??

Comment: you are sending data via ajax or normal form post (page refresh) is happening?

Comment: @AlivetoDie i want to send by normal from

Comment: {!! Form::open(array('method'=>'post','action' => 'GetmacaddressController@click','name'=>'frm1'))!!}

Comment: Add hidden input containing the data that you want for example !

Comment: you have to create hidden inputs with `name ="data-name"`  and `name="data-click"`

Comment: @Maraboc yes i see but i want to pass by data attribute how can??

Comment: @AlivetoDie  i see but i want to pass by data attribute how can??

Comment: @TheRock if 2 guys told you the same thing it means you can't do what you want. I'm the third to confirm that you must use hidden inputs to pass the data you want to the controller..

Comment: Okay thank for take your time to answer i am appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***If you want to post those two data through Normal Form Post.Then use `hidden input` fields:-***

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{$value->name}}" name="data-name"/>
<input type="hidden" value="{{$value->click}}" name="data-click"/>
```

***Or:-***

```
{{ Form::hidden('data-name', $value->name) }}
{{ Form::hidden('data-click', $value->click) }}
```

***Now on Controller side you will get it as :-***

```
$request->input('data-name')
$request->input('data-click');
```

Comment: better `$request->input('data-name')` instead of the `$_POST` thing :)

Comment: @AlivetoDie but when i use hidden i don want user click view source to see the result

Comment: @AlivetoDie how can i use it and hide from view source

Comment: Anyhow it will appear in view source, even your code data also. You can't hide it. even `display:none` also visible to the view source.

Comment: @TheRock  glad to help you :):)

Comment: I get Class 'Form' not found.  The blade doesn't seem to know about "Form" in {{ Form::...

Answer (score 2):

You can use hidden field for this or you have to use ajax.

```
@if ($value != '')
      {{ Form::hidden('somevalue', $value->name) }}
      {{ Form::hidden('somevalueclick', $value->click) }}
@endif
```